# Fast way to select small sample from huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, random, database-performance

The table I have is huge about 100+ million entries, it is ordered by default by 'A'. There could be many items with the same column A, A increases from 0 to... A big number. I tried TABLESAMPLE but it does not quite select a good number from each A number, it skips some of them or maybe I am not using it well. So I would like to select the same amount of values from each A number. And I would like the total of selected rows to be a number, let's say 10 million or let's call it B.

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: Seems like you want a very specific set, not a sample. Does the set of values from each A number need to be different / random every time you run the query? Can you describe the index(es) on the table? An important distinction: a table isn't "ordered by default" - a table is an unordered set of rows. While there may be a clustered index that dictates allocation order, not all queries will return data in that order and it shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: How many rows are there per value of "A"?

Comment: by ordered i mean indexed by A

Comment: i dont know how many rows there are for each value of A

Answer (score 2):

While it's not exactly clear to me what you need to achieve, when I have needed a large sample subset that is very well distributed between Parent and/or common Attribute values, I have done it like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   (YourID % 10) = 3
```

This also has the advantage that you can get another completely different sample just by changing the "3" to another digit.  Plus you can change the sub-sample size by adjusting the "10".

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `NEWID()`:

```
SELECT TOP 100
  *
FROM
  YourTable
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

@RBarryYoung solution is right, generic and it works for any constant statistic distribution, like id sequences (or any auto-increment column). Sometimes, though, your distribution is not constant or you can run into performance issues (SQL Server has to scan all index entries to calculate the WHERE clause).

If any of those affects your problem, consider the built-in T-SQL operator [`TOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) that may suit your needs:

```
SELECT TOP (30) PERCENT *
FROM YourTable;
```